# PATCH request using LocalServiceRegistry

Tags: webservices, commerce-cloud, service, b2c, demandware

I have a scenario where if the customer updates his/her profile in SFCC, then that customer has to be updated in the Salesforce Account object using a `PATCH` call. I was planning to use to the `HTTPService` class for this as this allows me to set the request method using the function `setRequestMethod()`.

Just for more clarity, I was going through its documentation and I saw that only the following methods can be set via above method: `GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE`

Now, I want to know, how can I make a `PATCH` call and can this be done using `HTTPService` class or is there any other class for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a PATCH call ( any method for that matter ). Here is an example of a POST call where you pass the method as a String.

https://github.com/taurgis/link_sentry/blob/7bed86793bec828ebf0ba2f7ebcd3c1116327ef4/cartridges/lib_sentry/cartridge/scripts/services/sentryService.js#L28